# Is is possible to multiply ranges and the sum over the new range in pages?

Tags: numbers

I want to multiply the price times quantity and summ it up. Obviously multiplying columns is not valid. I know i could make a second column where the "price X quantity" is represented and then summ it up. But I dont want some additional space be used, and I beleive numbers should be smart enough to handle this request. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found it out. There is a SUMPRODUCT() function, that multiply ranges. This makes the result

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D3:D15,C3:C15)
```